# how to make a python program using "while" to print at 0?

Tags: python, while-loop

My assignment is to make a program that prompts the user to input numbers to be categorized as even or odd. It will then add them together and count the amount of inputs of evens or odds. So far, I have that down, but I can't figure out how to get my program to run through the outputs when 0 is typed in.
Here's my code:

```
  number = int(input("Input an integer (0 terminates the program): "))
zero = 0
count_odd = 0
count_even = 0
odd_sum = 0
even_sum = 0
sum = float(count_odd) + float(count_even)

while number >= 0:
    if number%2 == 0:
        count_even+=1
        even_sum= even_sum + number
        number = int(input("Input an integer (0 terminates the program): "))
    elif number%2 != 0:
        count_odd+=1
        odd_sum = odd_sum + number
        number = int(input("Input an integer (0 terminates the program): "))
    elif number == zero:
        print("Sum of odds: " +odd_sum)
        print("Sum of evens: " + even_sum)
        print("Odd count: " +count_odd)
        print("Even count: " +count_even)
        print("Total positive int count:" +sum)
    else: 
        number = int(input("Input an integer (0 terminates the program): "))
```

I'm not even sure the ending is right at all. Especially not my attempt at creating a "zero."

Comment: There's a couple of things you need to take care of (tweak) before you besides why it's not ending at 0. I included helpful comments in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current program does not work because `0 % 2` is also `0` , so it will go into the `if` block and it will never reach the `elif number == zero:` block.

You should move your `elif` to the top to become an `if` and move the `if` to `elif` , for your logic to work. and also, if you want to loop to break at `0` , you should add `break` statement in the `number == zero` block. Example -

```
while number >= 0:
    if number == 0:
        print("Sum of odds: ", odd_sum)
        print("Sum of evens: ", even_sum)
        print("Odd count: ", count_odd)
        print("Even count: ", count_even)
        print("Total positive int count:", even_sum + odd_sum)
        break
    elif number%2 == 0:
        count_even+=1
        even_sum= even_sum + number
        number = int(input("Input an integer (0 terminates the program): "))
    elif number%2 != 0:
        count_odd+=1
        odd_sum = odd_sum + number
        number = int(input("Input an integer (0 terminates the program): "))
```

Other issues that I noticed in your program -

1. `"Sum of odds: " +odd_sum` would not work because you cannot add int and string like that, instead pass them as separate arguments to the `print` .
2. You do not need the `else:` part, as it would never reach there.

Answer (score 0):

When you input "0", this condition is `true` as well:

```
if number%2 == 0:
```

So your program counts the "0" as a valid input (an even number).

Try comparing with zero first, then the rest of the ifs.

Also, you should use a "break" to end the program when "0" is inputted.

Try this version:

```
    number = int(input("Input an integer (0 terminates the program): "))
    zero = 0
    count_odd = 0
    count_even = 0
    odd_sum = 0
    even_sum = 0
    sum = float(count_odd) + float(count_even)

    while number >= 0:
        if number == zero:
            print("Sum of odds: ", odd_sum)
            print("Sum of evens: ", even_sum)
            print("Odd count: ", count_odd)
            print("Even count: ", count_even)
            print("Total positive int count:", sum)
            break
        elif number%2 == 0:
            print "a"
            count_even+=1
            even_sum= even_sum + number
            number = int(input("Input an integer (0 terminates the program): "))
        elif number%2 != 0:
            count_odd+=1
            odd_sum = odd_sum + number
            number = int(input("Input an integer (0 terminates the program): "))
        else: 
            number = int(input("Input an integer (0 terminates the program): "))
```

Comment: Yeah I recognized that when I put it in python tutor. I'm just not sure how to keep the program recognizing evens as numbers that are divisible by two as well as terminate at 0.

Comment: Try the version I included in my answer. By asking for the "0" case first and breaking the loop, it terminates when you input a "0". It will count the numbers until you input "0".

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes and addressed them with comments, the main problem was that you should have been checking for zero with the first conditional statement in your while loop.

```
# Setup your variables
# I removed the input line from here, since we only need to get input in the while loop
count_odd = 0
count_even = 0
odd_sum = 0
even_sum = 0

# Use a simple boolean flag to tell the while loop to keep going
keep_going = True
while keep_going == True:

    # Grab the number from the user
    number = int(input("Input an integer (0 terminates the program): "))

    # IMPORTANT - Check for zero first
    # If it is zero, set out flag to false, so we will exit the while loop
    if number == 0:
        keep_going = False

    elif number % 2 == 0:
        count_even += 1
        even_sum += number

    elif number % 2 != 0:
        count_odd += 1
        odd_sum += number

# Here we have exited the while loop
sum = float(count_odd) + float(count_even)    

# Print everything here
```

Answer (score 0):

To fully make your script function you'll need this:

```
import sys # allows the script to end after 0 properly

number = int(input("Input an integer (0 terminates the program): "))
zero = 0
count_odd = 0
count_even = 0
odd_sum = 0
even_sum = 0
summation = float(count_odd) + float(count_even) # don't use sum because it's already taken by python, and you can also remove it, see below why

while number >= 0:
    if number%2 == 0 and number != 0:
        count_even+=1
        even_sum= even_sum + number
        number = int(input("Input an integer (0 terminates the program): "))
    elif number%2 != 0:
        count_odd+=1
        odd_sum = odd_sum + number
        number = int(input("Input an integer (0 terminates the program): "))
    elif number == 0: # pay attention to the concatenation of strings, not string and integer
        print("Sum of odds: " + str(odd_sum))
        print("Sum of evens: " + str(even_sum))
        print("Odd count: " + str(count_odd))
        print("Even count: " + str(count_even))
        summation = float(count_odd) + float(count_even)
        print("Total positive int count:" + str(summation)) # add everything up after it's been done NOT before
        sys.exit() # to stop your infinite loop
    else: 
        number = int(input("Input an integer (0 terminates the program): "))
```